Navicat for MySQL, 1045 error access is denied to a database using same settings on a new Macbook Pro
When I try to make a new connection to a remote MySQL database using the exact same settings that works on another MacOS, it gives me the error "1045 - Access Denied for user 'user'@'ipaddress' (using password: YES)" on Navicat for MySQL. The port is 3306 and I'm definitely giving it the right host name.  Use SSL is checked off.
I've installed Mysql on this particular machine using homebrew.
Does anybody know how to fix this error? There's no IP white listing
EDIT:
Output of: SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;



Host
User




localhost
mysql.infoschema


localhost
mysql.session


localhost
mysql.sys


localhost
root




Please add output of: SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;.  When the column Host does not have % (for the user you are talking about) you might need to do some research.  (see: this)

@Luuk Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Such output should not be in a comment. you should have used [edit] to add it to your question.
